# Need assistance dismissing modally presented ViewController and popping ViewController from UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue, nsnotificationcenter

[image]

**AppDelegate**

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSLog(@"applicationWillEnterForeground");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"applicationWillEnterForeground" object:nil];
}
```

**V1**

```
-(IBAction)uw:(UIStoryboardSegue*)segue{
    NSLog(@"Back on V1");
}
```

**V2**

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(goBackToV1) name:@"applicationWillEnterForeground" object:nil];
}

-(void)goBackToV1 {
    NSLog(@"goBackToV1");
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"uwid" sender:nil];
}
```

**V3**
present modally from `V2` and has no code.

After running the app I hit the home button and open the app again, this trigger notification and received by `V2`.

What `V2` is supposed to do:

1. Dismiss `V3`. If `V3` has no `ViewController` subclass then it is dismissed otherwise its not.
2. `V2` itself must be popped from `UINavigationController`, but it do not pop if `V3` is not dismissed but gives the log `goBackToV1`.

If on `V3` I do this `NSLog(@"%@", [self presentingViewController]);` I get `<UINavigationController: 0x13582d800>`

My question:

1. Why `V3` get dismissed when no ViewController subclass is assigned to it.
2. Why `V3` do not get dismissed when ViewController subclass is assigned to it.
3. Why `performSegueWithIdentifier` on `V2` didn't pop it to `V1` although the code get executed but its simple got ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if you have `presentedViewController` in **V2**, if you do, then dismiss it and in completion block perform the segue, otherwise perform the segue directly,

```
-(void)goBackToV1 {
    NSLog(@"goBackToV1");
    if(self.presentedViewController) {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"uwid" sender:nil];
        }];     
    } else {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"uwid" sender:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for solving my problem, please can you also explain according to the questions I asked?

Comment: probable because you are not dismissing the V3, therefore V2 is still required to be in the view hierarchy because it was the Presenting View Controller of V3

Comment: But why V3 get automatically get dismissed when no custom view controller class is assign to it in storyboard?